# At what point does everything become nothing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, big-bang, popular-science

I understand that the universe, which I'll call "everything", is expanding and it used to be much smaller. But I keep hearing assertions about a universe coming from nothing. If you rolled the clock back, at what point would everything become nothing?

Comment: Read [Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) on Wikipedia, and you will see that your assertion of "nothing" is wrong.

Comment: I am not asserting there was ever "nothing". Some people talk about a universe coming from nothing. Is there any scientific basis to assert that the universe came from nothing, if we define nothing as that which does not manifest in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @user1558225, these are actually philosophical questions that are arguably beyond the realm of science.  Unfortunately, some physicists are attempting to change the definition of "Nothing" from *the absence of anything* to well, something that is at least governed by physical law.  I look at it this way; the existence of physical law, and whatever it governs, is *something* and not *Nothing*.  Your question is interesting and I up voted because I like the way you posed it but, I'm afraid, it's not physics.

Comment: I would only accept "Science has nothing to say about it," from actual scientists. Thank you.

Comment: @user1558225, how interesting.  Isn't that a logical fallacy?  Also, what if *actual* scientists disagree?  What *are* you to do then?

Answer (score 2):

If you google for "age of the universe", you'll see a nice big fat

### 13.77 billion years

pop up :)

This is what you'll often see in popular science magazines or documentaries etc. This number is actually pretty meaningless in and by itself. It is a measure of the "intuitive" amount of time you'd have to go back in order to witness the birth of the universe. However, in current mainstream theory, *everything* got started then, also *time itself*. As this can get pretty confusing, the "13.77 Gy" is often used to simplify the details so the layman can understand it (for very short periods of time after the big bang, it is often more appropriate to speak in terms of energies, temperatures, etc. rather than time).

More to the core of your question however; big bang theory (arguably the best model for the long-term description of the universe there is) does **not** try to explain *where* the universe came from, it just provides a framework around what happened *after its inception*.

Where the universe came from, what caused it to come into being, whether it was nothing, or something, a white hole, or the collisions of branes, or a simple passing of another infinity in the cycle, *we do not know*.

There are many different views surrounding this particular matter, none of which are currently *really* accepted as mainstream physics. A few places to start reading:

- the [Ekpyrotic universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe)
- [Inflation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_inflation)
- [Cyclic universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_Model)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not asking when the big bang happened, or even what might have caused the big bang. I'm asking, in backward flowing time, would everything become nothing (i.e. cease to manifest in any way at all)? And if the answer is "we don't know", then is it in any way scientifically supported to assert that the universe came from nothing?

Comment: @user1558225: OK, I'm not sure I follow. In backward flowing time (supposing for the moment that such a thing is possible), you'd see the entire life of the universe in reverse, up until the big bang and initial singularity. How is your question then different from analyzing the initial singularity and the big bang? The initial singularity (and the primordial quark/gluon soup that came from it) are currently understood to contain *everything* that is currently in the universe (observable and non-observable), so...

Comment: There's a limit to our knowldege: the [planck time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time)

Comment: Thank you! If the initial singularity contains everything, then that is certainly not nothing. If the singularity has properties, then it is not nothing. It is just the universe in a different form, isn't it? Is there any scientific basis to assert that the universe came from nothing? Allowing for backward-flowing time, would there be a point at which the matter/energy of the universe ceased to exist altogether?

Comment: Maybe another way to ask this question is this... Is there any scientific evidence to suggest that the singularity didn't exist before it did? Is there reason to be believe there was ever not something with observable properties?

Comment: @user1558225: If there ever was something without any observable properties, how would any science ever be able to prove or disprove its existence (given that all scientific endeavors have observability at their core)? The only way to "prove" it is then indirectly, for example, by coming up with a theory that is consistent with everything that is observable, and which predicts that everything came from something that had no observable properties. But that is not actually proof; that initial "nothingness" is an unprovable extrapolation of the theory.

Comment: @user1558225: This is somewhat reminiscent of how science deals with God; you can't prove nor disprove that God exists, even in principle. Therefore, within the realm of science, it is pointless to even consider the question of God's existence. These are simply not questions that science can answer.